# Passenger manifests - internal sailings uk?

Tags: military-records, united-kingdom, sources, manifest, ship

Being ignorant of these matters I presume a list/timetable of sailings still exists.

from this I might be able to shortlist any sailing that might give me the information I'm searching for.

Firstly, have these survived in any form- if they ever existed?

If there are surviving records where and how would you access them? digitised?

---

As I have only just scratched the surface on this- I presume the lists of foreign ports calling at several uk ports will have the internal travellers listed.

---

I suppose a bit of background could help you to to help me.

Sidney had seen service in the Boer war.On his way back he reached the end of his service. They disembarked and went to Fermoy barracks and soon absconded.

I don't know if this was commonplace or not but I'm wondering could he have gone back on the ship that carried the rest of his unit(presumably he knew the details)?

Would/should this have been recorded in his record (which it wasn't)?

Would they have listing for who was on troopships?

Comment: Can you specify a time period please -- it will affect the answer.

Comment: Also, it you could specify what information you're actually looking for, we will be able to suggest alternative research routes.

Comment: Further to this - I presume the captains' logs and crew lists have been kept and digitized. What sort of information might go on this. As many a bloke, and lass for that matter, got into mischief at this time would they get mentioned in say the logs- as many fights must have broken out. - so many questions, too few answers?

Comment: ok- a sidney james block was in the border regiment and he was at a garrison town near cork. He deserted on april 1st 1901 and then popped up again when he married Wandsworth on 15th June 1901  - my mother wonders what happened in between time. - how did he get from Fermoy to Wandsworth- must've been a ship.Whart sources might have useful information on what he did in the meantime?

Comment: Paul, if you click on the edit button under your question you can add that info into the text.

Answer (score 4):

Passenger lists were not required for travel within the UK, or even between the UK and Europe. See [TNA Passenger Lists Guide](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/passengers/). The one exception to that is when "a ship called at more than one European port before travelling further afield." And vice versa for inbound traffic. So far as I know all passenger traffic between Ireland and mainland Britain was ferry traffic so no lists were kept (caveat - I'm *fairly* certain that I've read about people getting off a west-bound Transatlantic at Cobh - then Queenstown - but I *personally* doubt this was normal ferry traffic).

Shipping timetables - interesting question. I would suggest [The British Newspaper Archive](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/) as a starter, looking for ferry advertisements. You may find basic timetables there and certainly names of shipping companies and ports.

If Sidney sailed as crew, then you need to look for Crew List Agreements and while the vast majority survive, up to 80% are in Newfoundland, and few are digitised / indexed. See [TNA Crew Lists Guide](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/crew-lists-agreements-log-books-merchant-ships-1861/).